# How can I move a folder without encountering issues related to cyclic folders and excessive disk space consumption?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, robocopy, junction

I'm using the following command to move a folder:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\TTHCMM" "D:\C_Drive\Users\TTHCMM" /E /MT:32 /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS
```

However, I've noticed that this command can sometimes result in cyclic folders, which can be caused by Juncture folders, and it can also consume a large amount of disk space. For example, while the source folder `"C:\Users\TTHCMM"` may only have around 10GB of data, the destination folder "D:\C_Drive\Users\TTHCMM" can occupy several terabytes of memory.

After investigating the issue, I found that the problem is specifically caused by the following two folders:

```
D:\C_Drive\Users\TTHCMM\Local Settings\Application Data
D:\C_Drive\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Local\Application Data
```

As extra information: when I run the command `dir /a:l` in the source folder `"C:\Users\TTHCMM"`, I get the following result:

```
[D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\.PyCharm2019.1]
    10/23/2021  09:49 AM    <JUNCTION>     .PyCharm2019.3 [D:\C_Drive\Hardlink\.PyCharm2019.3]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     Application Data [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     Cookies [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     Local Settings [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Local]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     My Documents [C:\Users\TTHCMM\Documents]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     NetHood [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
    05/14/2023  12:52 AM    <DIR>          OneDrive
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     PrintHood [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     Recent [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     SendTo [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     Start Menu [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
    01/14/2022  05:04 PM    <JUNCTION>     Templates [C:\Users\TTHCMM\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates]
                   0 File(s)              0 bytes
```

How could I copy the folder correctly without having this issue?